# Horizontal List Scrolling with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal scroller similar to those lists seen on netflix. This is the basic set-up of the html:

This is an image that I will use to explain my efforts:
[image]

The upper set-up is what I want: scrolling_list has a set width (i set it to, say, 300px). Then, inside this div I have a list scroller that will host multiple children called outer_list. The upper setup shows how the list_scroller will have a width expanding with the number of children (1000, 1300, 1600 or whatever depending on the number of children).

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this with the css.. right now, unless I specify the width of list_scroller, its width won't expand (it'll assume the width of the first child). Instead, the list_scroller assumes this shorter width and then the children end up stacking horizontally.

Can anyone help me fix this? Here is the current css:

```
.scrolling_list {
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:360px;
}
.list_scroller {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    height:360px;
}
.list_scroller .outer_list {
    width:260px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: put some example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: How can you make it scroll with the mouse and each row not be tied to the other rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track! I think instead of setting `overflow: auto;` and `overflow-y: hidden;`, you should just set the whole overflow to hidden, and give the list_scroller a bigger width. Something like this might work:

http://jsfiddle.net/mEg7g/1/

Good luck, I hope this helps. :D

Comment: thanks, this is great - just had to switch .scrolling_list to overflow:auto; makes everything work right. THANKS SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space:nowrap` for the container : http://jsfiddle.net/BQGa7/

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget to add

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* I guess iOS 5 only */
```

For iOS devices compatibility.

Comment: It's not a standardized property, so do [not](http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/02/09/CALL-FOR-ACTION:-THE-OPEN-WEB-NEEDS-YOU-NOW) use it.

Comment: @boudou Works for me on my iOS devices, and it makes the overflow so smooth, I really really really recommend it. By default, these devices don't support div scrolling.

Comment: @boudou The stuff written [link](http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2012/02/09/CALL-FOR-ACTION:-THE-OPEN-WEB-NEEDS-YOU-NOW)[/link] is quite good, good job, even I think so, but at times, to make your stuff work on majority devices, we do need these properties, like, this overflow scrolling property can be avoided at the cost of several kbs of javascript with CSS or just one single line of css, you see..., similarly, things like, -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);, -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;, needs to be there in every good website. :)

Comment: By the way, this is somehow resolved by [link]http://prefixr.com it automatically adds the ms-, moz-, etc, I think the new version of Dreamweaver should have this thing through its API, it will somewhat make the website future proof, somewhat. The webkit has indeed taken the minds of designers, even though firefox still remains quite, all the CSS3 properties are much better enacted by it as compared to Chrome.