# Scroll a div on button mouseover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to continuously scroll through a div on jQuery when mousing over another. In other words, I want to be able to have one div, named right_scroll_bar, scroll the div scrolling_list:

```
    $('.right_scroll_button').hover(function(){
     $('.scrolling_list').//something to make it scroll continuously    
});
```

I tried setting up a jsfiddle, but the javascripts don't seem to be running right..
http://jsfiddle.net/fjnXn/2/

Comment: Is what you mean "content appearing/loading whenever the content box reaches end on scroll"? As it works in Facebook?

Comment: no.. just scrolling through the div. IE .scrolling_list has content that is wider than it, it scrolls through it horizontally.. i want a button to be able to enable a user to do that scrolling if they want

Comment: eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402082/horizontal-list-scrolling-with-css

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a carousel?  If so, don't try to re-invent the wheel, there are several good and free jQuery carousels out there.  One of the more popular seems to be [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/).  Just [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jQuery%20carousel#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=J01H0gOnRGisuGKSxJ4J9g&pq=jcarousel%20lite&cp=9&gs_id=1z&xhr=t&q=jquery%20carousel&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery%20ca&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=af35eef1e8b7fba5&biw=1355&bih=784) jQuery Carousel and you get several topics of interest.

Comment: yeah, i know those exist... but what's the fun in that? learning about jquery, and getting better at building awesome UIs... that's what i'm trying to do here.

Comment: I feel you on that.  There's nothing wrong though with looking at their code to see how specific tasks are performed.  As long as you don't plagiarize their work, there's nothing wrong with learning from it.

Comment: do you see a continuous scroll option on this? (like on netflix)

Comment: You could [try something like this](http://www.egrappler.com/contents/jscarouselv2/demo/jscarousel-2.0.0.htm) and mess around with the `onClick` events of the plugin to create your hover effects.

Comment: [Here's something](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal_manual.html) that might be closer to what your looking for.  Download it and dissect it. Again, nothing wrong with looking at other code for help, ideas and knowledge.